# Sql Server Compare Application

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare

I want to know is what is the best sql server comparison tool application on the market?

I recently noticed an app which I loved and posted a question about BUT with a link to the website. Bad mistake, was naive.

I do a lot of programming and database development at home and have been using Red Gate (licence supplied by work while I work at h0me) but as I am leaving in 2 weeks time, I am desperate for a replacement BUT cheap replacement.

I apologise for recent posting where I typed in the url link (which was removed), but I will NOT type in the url of the recent web site but I am genuine in finding a good cheap replacement. I am new to StackOverFlow (use it a lot but never added a question - never needed to until now)

Rob

Comment: Do you want to compare the data or the structures ?

Comment: Both. I found a website as you know and the product was $49 personal for both schema and data? I can get a buy one get one free. I have used it and it's brilliant but I just wish someone could view it for me and let me know if I see a Redgate app worth much much less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like what you're looking for ? http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/

Comment: OK. Not sure how I missed this one. I will check it out. It's free as well which I like :)

Comment: Impressed. Like it for a free product. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The best? RedGate's Sql Compare (as you referenced). Free? No clue.

**Remember:** *you get what you pay for.*

Comment: Red Gate has been great but have experienced issues with it.

Comment: Red-Gate is the best - hands down. No comparison. Get it, use it, be happy!

Comment: Not what I have seen! You were the one that removed my previous post, but did you check out the url... you have nothing to lose. It was hands down!

Answer (score 2):

We use Database Comparer 2010 for SQLServer from EMS Database Management Solutions.

It fits our needs and isn't really expensive (80 Euro Bucks or what). It can do nearly everything.

Comment: Wish I could add 1 to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

u can use VS2010 premium or Ultimate edition.

Comment: How? I'm confused. Free extension addon?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of years ago I also was looking for database comparison tool; couldn't find one so I wrote one - I named it "SQL Server Comparison Tool". I sell it on the internet since then - you can try it and if you like it please let me know (I have no problem with giving it for free for individual developers).

I hope that my post doesn't break any rules of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg427686) is a free IDE for database development that includes a full-featured schema comparison tool. It's based on Visual Studio, but you don't need a Visual Studio license to run it, as it will install a basic VS2010 shell if required. The finished product will be shipped with SQL Server 2012 and as part of Visual Studio 11, but is available *now* for download and working with 2005 and 2008 DBs.

It does a lot more besides just schema comparison. It's a full database development environment, where you can create projects that manage all your DB code and objects. It's pretty rad.